# Add new html table, under the existing table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have an html table and a Javascript code which adds a new table under this by pressing the "add new table" button. The problem is that when I am refreshing the page, the table that just added disappeared. How can I make it to remain after added, when I am refreshing the page?

```
<table border="0" style="margin: auto; ">

<td width="60%" >

<fieldset style="width:530px; padding-left:5px; background-color:white " >

<INPUT type="button" value="Add new Table" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

School/University/College*</br>
<input name="school_1" type="text" size="73"/>
</br></br>
Field of Study</br>
<input name="field_1" type="text" size="73"/>
</br></br>
Specialized subjects</br>
<input name="specialized_subject_1" type="text" size="73" />
</br></br>
Degree</br>
<input name="degree_1" type="text" size="73"/>
</br></br>
Grade</br>
<input name="grade_1" type="text" size="73" />
</br></br></br>

    Attended from:&nbsp;<select name="month_1_1"> 
    <option value=" "> EMPTY </option> 
    <option value="January">January</option> 
    </select>

    <select id="year_1_1" name="year_1_1"> 
    <option value=" "> EMPTY </option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
   </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    Until:&nbsp;<select name="month_1_2"> 
    <option value=" "> EMPTY </option> 
    <option value="January">January</option>                        
    </select>

    <select name="year_1_2"> 
    <option value=" "> EMPTY </option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
   </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;    

</h2></font>
</fieldset>

</td>

</table>
```

and this is the Javascript code:

```
 <SCRIPT language="javascript">
   function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                    break;
            case "select-one":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                    break;
        }
    }
  }


</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: You'd have to either overwrite the existing html page, I'm not sure that's something you want to do. Either that or let the user save a new html page to the server, which would require giving write access to that user.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not write to the file. So, changes are only available while you are on the page. I wouldn't want a user to be able to edit the HTML file directly either.

If you need them to persist and the changes are for a specific user, you could save their options (i.e. number of tables added) and have the server-side (PHP or w/e) add the tables when the page is served up.

Comment: got any link of such an example?

Comment: It would depend on what kind of server-side language you wanted to use and your level of knowledge with accessing databases/sessions (for users log in)/etc

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the refresh is basically asking for the page from scratch, so the server is giving the client the page as if it is a new request.

This is why you need to save the state of the page (or at least the users data) somewhere, there are multiple ways to do this, using the viewstate is one or a session variable is another.

That way when you load the page the first thing you should do is load information back onto the page that is stored (in the viewstate or the session) - see ASP.NET or other equivalent technology.

If you have no way of maintaining the "state" of a page (i.e. your not running a web application, you are just serving a HTML page with some javascript) then you need to make sure the user cannot refresh the page or pop something up reminding them that their preferences are not stored (either way it gets a bit un-friendly to use).

- You cannot allow users to write the page back to the server as this will only work for one person at a time and is not good practice at all really.